# React: Uncaught TypeError: this.state.data.map is not a function and

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I did some digging on this already but haven't come up with a good solution yet. A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39329100/uncaught-typeerror-this-state-data-map-is-not-a-function) but my difference is that I'm not trying to pass a `string` to the `map()` method.

Anyways, I'm just building a simple weather checked app using React, I'm using the API from [Open Weather Map API](https://openweathermap.org/forecast5) 5 day forecast.

The API works fine, I can log the data to my console using the below:

```
componentDidMount () {
    axios.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=London,uk&appid=APIKEY')
        .then(response => {
           console.log(response.data);
        });

}
```

But, when I got to map it to my array of component, I get the error from above, saying that `this.state.forecasts.map()` is not a function:

**Weather.js**

```
class Weather extends Component {

    state = {
        forecasts: []
      }

    componentDidMount () {
        axios.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=London,uk&appid=APIKEY')
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({forecasts: response.data});
            });

    }

    render() {

        const projections = this.state.forecasts.map(forecast => {
            return (<Subweather
                    date={forecast.dt_txt}
                    //temp={day.temp}
                    key={forecast.id}  /> );
        });
return (
            <div className={classes.WeatherDiv}>
                {projections}
            </div>
```

I'm a little confused as to what I'm missing here, any suggestions?

Comment: did you log response.data as far as i know it will not return array

Comment: yes sorry, i had a typo and fixed it above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

```
this.setState({forecasts: response.data});
```

with

```
this.setState({forecasts: response.data.list});
```

Comment: bingo. i wasn't actually trying to access the array and map it. That makes sense now, thank you!