# React TypeError: this.state.projects.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
export default class Timeline extends Component{
state = {
    projects : [],
};

async componentDidMount(){
    const response = await api.get("/projects");

    this.setState({projects: response.data});
}

render(){
    return (
        <div className="timeline-wrapper">
           { this.state.projects.map(project => <h1>{project.name}</h1> )}
         </div>

    );       
}


}
```

This code returns

> TypeError: this.state.projects.map is not a function

Why? what is the problem here?

Appreciate!

Comment: What is `response.data`?

Comment: response.data is actually a promise I guess ... not your response array of objects ... you need to `await` for it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError: this.state.data.map is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39329100/uncaught-typeerror-this-state-data-map-is-not-a-function)

Comment: What do you get if you add `console.log(response)` after `const response...`?

Answer (score 0):

if you're using axios as I gussed..

```
const res = await axios.get(queryString);
  const arrayOfObjects = await res.data; // << what you use for map
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem yesterday and solved it today. I would like to share it here and hopefully it can help you or others looking to solve this issue.

I was working on a full-stack app and the problem lies in my back end.

The way I returned the response was wrong because it returned as an object and it had to be an array and I wanted to map through it.

```
Project.find({})
.then(projects=> {

//This is wrong:

res.json({projects: projects})

}
```

```
Project.find({})
.then(projects=> {

//This is correct:

res.json(projects)
}
```

That's all I had to change. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that your promise returned an empty result, meaning the *response.data* is undefined.

After you call set state, you change the default array to undefined, which means that *this.state.projects* cannot be mapped as it is no longer an array.

For me, that is ok, as you should probably set the default state to be undefined and handle that situation.

You can try changing the code like this:

```
export default class Timeline extends Component {
  state = {
    projectsLoading: false,
    projects: undefined
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ projectsLoading: true }, async () => {
      const response = await api.get('/projects');
      this.setState({ projects: response.data, projectsLoading: false });
    });
  }

  renderProjects() {
    const { projects } = this.state;

    projects
      ? projects.map(project => <h1>{project.name}</h1>)
      : 'There are currently no projects to show';
  }

  render() {
    const { projectsLoading } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="timeline-wrapper">
        {projectsLoading ? <Loader /> : this.renderProjects()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This would add support for loading when your data is being fetched from api, an error message if the data returned is blank, and handle the undefined situation.