# Return JSON and print out reactJS

Tags: json, reactjs, axios

You would think that returning data from a JSON file would be simple, however my attempts have failed.

The basic concept is the following

```
class News extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            data: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://api.drn1.com.au/api-access/news')
        .then(({ data })=> {
            this.setState({
                data: data
            });
        });
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <Container maxWidth="lg">
        <Helmet>
            <meta charSet="utf-8" />
            <title>DRN1 :: Latest News</title>
            <link rel="canonical" href={document.location} />
        </Helmet>
        <ComingSoon />

        {this.state.data.map(news => <div>{news.title+' '+news.url}</div>)}

        </Container>
      );
    }
  }

  export default News;
```

However it seems to be throwing errors.

```
TypeError: this.state.data.map is not a function
News.render
src/components/News.js:67
  64 |     <title>DRN1 :: Latest News</title>
  65 |     <link rel="canonical" href={document.location} />
  66 | </Helmet>
> 67 | <ComingSoon />
     | ^  68 | 
  69 | {this.state.data.map(news => <div>{news.title+' '+news.url}</div>)}
  70 | 
View compiled
▶ 17 stack frames were collapsed.
(anonymous function)
src/components/News.js:53
  50 | componentDidMount() {
  51 |     axios.get('http://api.drn1.com.au/api-access/news')
  52 |     .then(({ data })=> {
> 53 |         this.setState({
     | ^  54 |             data: data
  55 |         });
  56 |     });
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39329100/uncaught-typeerror-this-state-data-map-is-not-a-function

Comment: comment the line that has the `.map` to remove the error, and add a `console.log(this.state.data)`, check to see if it's an array or not

Comment: @MoIsmat the following worked console.log(this.state.data.news);

but how do i print it (foreach?)

Comment: @RussellHarrower can you provide what you are getting in this.state.data when console logged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are getting you data. Make sure your data should be an **Array** not string

```
renderData(){
    return this.state.data.map(m => <div>{m.title + '' + m.url}</div>)
}
```

Add this

```
render() {
      return (
        <Container maxWidth="lg">
        <Helmet>
            <meta charSet="utf-8" />
            <title>DRN1 :: Latest News</title>
            <link rel="canonical" href={document.location} />
        </Helmet>
        <ComingSoon />

        {this.renderData}

        </Container>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

axios.get('http://api.drn1.com.au/api-access/news') returns as follows:

```
{'news': [{}, {}, ...]}
```

So you should iterate data.news, not data.